# Several projection issues QGIS 3.4.3

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

1) Whether I run a processing algorithm or just try to export to another CRS the layer is being output as a different CRS, eg. EPSG:102003 returns USER:100026. EPSG:102005 returns USER:100030

It is creating problems with the processing modeler and it's annoying to have to check every layer to see if the CRS has been maintained or changed.

*the next issues are probably related to the first*

2) Layers with the same CRS do not line up.

3) 102005 is projected sideways

[image]

[image]

All my data is in North America. I updated from 3.2 because of a bug in the raster calculator that caused it to fail in the processing modeler.  I didn't have any CRS issues in 3.2.

Comment: What are your settings for the CRS of new layers? What version of QGIS were you using before?

Comment: I have a default setting 102003.  I was using 3.2

Comment: Now that I mess with it I'm having all kinds of projection issues.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Same behavior here, in QGIS 3.4.4. Trying to save an EPSG:4326 shapefile to EPSG:102003 shapefile or geopackage. CRS tab log: `WARNING    Saved user CRS [+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs]` and `WARNING    Transform error caught: Could not transform bounding box to target CRS`. Messages tab log: `WARNING    CRS was undefined : defaulting to CRS EPSG:4326 - WGS 84`. EPSG:102003 definition: `+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs`.

Comment: If I change the QGIS 3.4.4 Settings > Options > CRS, and Use EPSG:102003 as default layer CRS, exporting to shapefile the new layer assumes the user CRS without warning. Exporting to geopackage the new layer assumes the default CRS (EPSG:102003) with the Messages tab log: `WARNING    CRS was undefined : defaulting to CRS EPSG:102003 - USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic`.

Comment: https://epsg.io/102003 says: `Description: +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m no_defs`. But the PROJ.4 string is not defining the `+ellps` parameter. I don't know but that can be the problem?

Comment: No, it isn't. You are an OSGeo4W user? Now, the problem seems to me like "Any EPSG code that is not stored in the `\share\proj\epsg` file is recognized in that sense, but are codes in esri, in esri.extra, etc". `cs2cs` don't recognize that projections also.

Comment: `cs2cs -v +init=epsg:102003` returns `Invalid projection system`, but `cs2cs -v +init=esri:102003` works fine. So, for `proj` that's an esri code, not an epsg code.

Comment: There is no EPSG code 102003, I used https://www.epsg-registry.org/ to double check

Comment: GDAL and PROJ handle the ESRI codes differently. While PROJ expects the `esri:` prefix, GDAL has them in the `epsg:` namespace. I don't know why.

Comment: Regarding the missing `+ellps`: `+datum=NAD83`includes the ellipsoid parameter values. You can test it with `gdalsrsinfo "+proj=merc+datum=NAD83"`.

Answer (score 3):

QGIS is not recognizing the `AUTHORITY ["Esri",` part of the *.qpj* file.

This is the content of the *qpj* file:

```
PROJCS["USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic",
    GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
        SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]], 
    PROJECTION["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",-96.0],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",29.5],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",45.5],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",37.5],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0],
    AUTHORITY["Esri","102003"]]
```

I'm not sure if the mistake is made by writing it or reading it.
It may be well written and QGIS should read it like that.
But if it is changed by `AUTHORITY["EPSG"`, QGIS reads it correctly and assigns the corresponding CRS to that layer.

Consequently, the projection is considered invalid (it would act in the same way if the *qpj* file did not exist) and creates a custom CRS by extracting the parameters from the *prj* file, and applies the custom CRS to the layer. I understand that this is the expected behavior for the projections provided by Esri.

If the layer was saved in a geopackage file, QGIS does not recognize the projection either, but acts according to the *Settings > Options > CRS*.

These behaviors were tested in OSGeo4W installations of `qgis-3.4.4-2` and `qgis-dev-3.5.0-76` packages.

A bug report was opened: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21122

Comment: Well, damn.  Do you know of a work around for this until it can get resolved?  It's slowing down two of my projects right now

Comment: No. I do not think it was an update of QGIS that caused the inconvenience, but rather an update of GDAL/OGR that started writing the _.qpj_ files in this way and QGIS is not yet adequate. The fault is also seen in QGIS 2.18. Do you have any layer of the ones produced previously to know how the _.qpj_ file was written?

Comment: Yes, several.  How do I check the .qpj file?

Comment: It is in the same folder and with the same name that the _.shp_ file. Open it with a text editor.

Comment: Ha, I did not see it there.  So on 2.18 it was coded as AUTHORITY["EPSG","102003"],  3.4.3 it's codes as AUTHORITY["Esri","102003"]  I can't find any examples from 3.2.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on 3.4.4.  Editing the .gpj solves the problem when loading the shape file, but saving the shape file to a geopkg causes the problem to reappear.